# xpath with multiple conditions which will contain 'a' and 'div' tag

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

Below is the full HTML tag where I want to use xpath with multiple conditions.

```html
<div class="request-body comments-left-discription clickme" style="cursor:pointer; " id="12340" title="" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" mode="">
        <div class="desc-title">
            <a target="_blank" class="site-color" href="http://test://0316">Nutan</a> requested <a href="http://test://0316">Approval</a></div>
            <div class="msg-time"><small><a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" class="color6" href="#" data-original-title="Created on, ">ago</a>  (020 )</small></div>
            Auto            <br>
            <div class="btn" id="button">
                <a id="accept" class="b" href="javascript:void(0);">APPROVE</a><a id="reject" class="btn" href="javascript:void(0);">REJECT</a>                </div>    
            </div>
```

In the above HTML I want to use the below conditions in one xpath statement and I have written like this below and it shows unable to locate element.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'1234')"
                + " and //a[contains(text(),'off')]]]"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` tag is beneath the `div` tag, so you can use the given below relative xpath for this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'5e9b7')]//a[contains(text(),'Compensatory-off Approval')]"))
```

**Updated answer after discussion with OP:**

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'5e9b7')]//a[contains(text(),'Compensatory-off Approval')]"));
if(elementList.size()>0){
    // Element is present
    // Do the required operations here
}
```

Comment: I have a code which contains several text labels and several buttons. I want to verify if the above condition is true then click on a certain button.

Comment: @vishalgupta you can check if the element is present on the page by getting its list size and then you can do the required operations. I have added the updated code in the ans, you can check that